# writing from right to left in php and display all the chars

Tags: php, laravel

I want to write with arabic in a picture, but the direction is always from left to right
so this is my code

```
public function generatePoster(Request $request,Arabic $obj) {
        $title = $request->get('title');
        $title =$obj->utf8Glyphs($title,20,false,true);
        $imgPath = public_path('storage/ichecktemplate.jpg');
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
        $fontSize = 30 ;
        $font = public_path('Almarai-Bold.ttf')
        $x = 640;
        $y = 364;
        imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $color, $font, $title);

        imagejpeg($image, 'save.jpg', 100);
}
```

my input : ابتثجحدحدذر زسشصض طعغفقك لمنهو يءأإآةؤ ئى
and this is what i get

[image]

Comment: I have found this gd library. https://github.com/cyc0der/gd-text-farsi. You could give a try with your glyphs

Comment: how to use it ?

Comment: Copy content of src inside app/Helpers ie. And run composer dumpautoload, later you can use as any other classes you create inside Laravel.

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: https://ibb.co/dLFVJ9W

Comment: I think you must adjust the below link file to be in arabic or nothing will work. But ok probably it doesn't work. I did not test it

Comment: thank you i figured out the problem was from the library that I am using, and the owner gonna fix it in the new version

Answer (score -1):

Use direction attribute in your input tag. you did not specify how your text input looks like but I am assuming something akin to this

```
<input type="text" dir="rtl" id="arabic"/>
```

Comment: I am writing with php on picture there is no html